# Move millions of files to root of S3

Tags: php, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-io

I have 20 million local files. Each file is represented by a numeric ID that is hashed.

File 1 is named `356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab` (sha1 of "1")

File 2 is named `da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0` (sha1 of "2")

etc. etc.

Not every number represent a file, but i have a list of all numbers that do.

The files are placed in folders named after the first two characters in the hash, followed by the next two, followed by the next two.

For file 1 (`da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0`) the folder structure is

`da/4b/92/`

In that folder the file is placed and it's named it's full hash, so the full path of the file is

`da/4b/92/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0`

I now want to move all the files from the file system to a bucket at Amazon S3, and *while doing so I want to move them out to the root* of that bucket.

As there are so many files it would be good if there was a way to log what files have been moved and what files might have failed for some reson, i need to be able to resume the operation if it fails.

My plan is to create a table in mysql called `moved_files` and then run a PHP script that fetches X number of ID's from the `files` table, uses the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) to copy the file to S3, if it succeeds it add that ID to the `moved_files` table. However I'm not sure if this would be the fastest way to do it, maybe I should look into writing a bash script using the [AWS Cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that a linux box? If so use sh

Comment: It is.

I do mention using the AWS Cli in the end of my question, but what I'm not sure about is exactly how to do this. First of all i need to make sure all files end up in the root of the S3, not just a copy of the file structure on the server.

Then I also want to make sure that moving the files one by one is the most optimal way to do it, i was thinking that maybe there is a way to move many files at ones and not have to open new connections to S3 for every file etc.

Comment: use "find + aws cli  + echo to log which files have been successfully transfered". 
pseudo code would be: for file in $(find /my/dirs/ -type f);do aws s3 cp $file s3://my-bucket/ && echo "successfully copied $file over" || echo "failed copying $file"; done

Comment: How about deleting the files locally on a successful move, then if you are interrupted, any that are still there locally have not been moved.

Comment: I suspect **GNU Parallel** might be a good way of ensuring you continuously keep moving 4-8 files in parallel and soak up all available bandwidth.

Comment: Be aware that aws s3 sync and aws s3 cp --recursive already include some level of parallelism. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-the-most-out-of-the-amazon-s3-cli/

Answer (score 3):

I do NOT use AWS S3, but a little Googling suggests you need a command like:

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

So, if you want to run that for all your files, I would suggest you use **GNU Parallel** to keep your connection fully utilised and to reduce latencies.

Please make a test directory with a few 10s of files to test with, then `cd` to that directory and try this command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run aws s3 cp {} s3://rootbucket/{/}
```

**Sample Output**

```
aws s3 cp ./da/4b/92/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0 s3://rootbucket/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0
aws s3 cp ./da/4b/92/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b1 s3://rootbucket/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b1
```

If you have 8 CPU cores, that will run 8 parallel copies of `aws` at a time till all your files are copied.

The `{}` expands to mean *"the current file"*, and `{/}` expands to mean *"the current file without its directory"*.  You can also add `--bar` to get a progress bar.

If that looks hopeful, we can add a little `bash` function for each file that updates your database, or deletes the local file, conditionally upon the success of the `aws` command. That looks like this - start reading at the bottom ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

# bash function to upload single file
upload() {
   local="$1"                                         # Pick up parameters
   remote="$2"                                        # Pick up parameters
   echo aws s3 cp "$local" "s3://rootbucket/$remote"  # Upload to AWS
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      : # Delete locally or update database with success
   else
      : # Log error somewhere
   fi
}

# Export the upload function so processes started by GNU Parallel can find it
export -f upload

# Run GNU Parallel on all files
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 upload {} {/}
```

Comment: There is --recursive flag to move folders

Comment: @titogeo Thank you - though AFAIK, OP wants to strip the folder name.

Comment: @titogeo Also, OP wants to check and record success of each file individually, so I am not sure how that would work if we did a whole directory recursively in one go.

Comment: You'll need the bucket name for the S3 copy, for example: aws s3 cp a/b/c/xyz s3://mybucket/xyz.

Comment: @jarmod Oh, I see! Thank you for the correction - I'll update shortly. I was kind of thinking the root bucket was un-named! As I said, I don't use `aws`. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Damn. Thanks for this answer! I can absolutely work with this. Great explanation too!

Gonna try it out on a section of the files and just see if it gets me where I want.

Comment: Cool - once it works, try `parallel -j 32 ...` to do 32 files in parallel if the files are small. Maybe check if there is a timeout parameter for `aws` command you can set to stop it hanging up if the network connection is flakey - we check for errors anyway so there's nothing lost.